# Front end registration form stopped working

Tags: ee2, solspace-user, registration

The front end registration form on my client's site takes the info and even acknowledges success - and the admin gets notified. But the info isn't getting into the db/ee back end anymore.

This registration form has been working OK for years, the rest of the site is OK as well.

The form uses User 3.4.5 which is no longer supported by Solspace.

The site was recently moved to a new server - en masse with the rest of my hosted accounts.

---

My server admin looked at this and here's what he got when he turned on error reporting. I have no idea how to use this information.

A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1366
Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'last_activity' at row 1
INSERT INTO exp_members (group_id, username, password, salt, ip_address, unique_id, join_date, email, screen_name, time_format, url, location, occupation, interests, language, last_activity, bday_d, bday_m, bday_y, aol_im, yahoo_im, msn_im, icq, bio, profile_views, timezone, signature) VALUES (4, 'mobin', '42b3f050b4c607c33200dde2ab4f3df36ea3b7b35dc26b283055f6e03ed600912a722257daf584162a46c7ab818ef727bd455cb6eb033840e3192e3066aee0d3', 'm0)ByGfjPC>\'sA=$*j6>NAX\"QU?,M8XghPKF(/\"@u*c\.N=T-v,I\'@K$RaaD=uf-uE>yV,SCRbBb#~AxGOC0OscBE%:3i?6~F]EnEl.}C(&3vB?#/7)I!S:~Qh\'zs,', '123.63.124.188', 'f8f835d49114da34eabf03cc60d807a7adda72b2', 1474251848, 'mobin.xavier@idologic.com', 'Mobin Idologic', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '')
Filename: third_party/user/mod.user.php

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it might be a system path issue somewhere.
Check your config file and other system settings.
Try turning on error reporting, level 2 (show errors to all) and try a registration. See if any errors report back. The obvious thing you changed was migrating to another server. Is the php version the same? php configuration the same?

Comment: My server admin looked at this and here's whart he got when he turened on error repostrting

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be mysql wasn't in strict mode on the old server, it was on the new one, so we disabled that and everything was fine again. :)